# Are inner function declarations safe?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

```
function outer(x) {
    function inner(y) {
        if (y) console.log(y);
        else console.log(42);
    }
    inner(x + 1);
}
outer(5); // expect a logging of '6'
inner(); // expect a Reference Error
```

I know what it is supposed to do and I expect it to do just that but are there any cross-browser quirks or side effects I should be aware of when declaring inner functions.

[Edit]

By safe I meant is it possible they pollute global namespaces or are not treated as being local to the function they were declared in.

[/Edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik no. IE has problems with *named function expressions* like:

```
var inner = function inner2() {

}
```

but everything else should be fine.

Comment: Does that named function expression when used as an inner function hoist the scope of the funcion `inner` to global namespace?

Comment: @Raynos: No, IE just creates two functions instead of one, but they stay in the same scope.

Comment: Are there any strange side effects of using `var name = function name() { ... }` Where your using the same name for the function declaration & function expression in IE?

Comment: @Raynos: Not 100% sure. The worse thing is that IE would still create two functions but one name would shadow the other one.

Answer (score 0):

That's regular ECMAScript syntax. It allows for closures and "inner functions". Statements (function declarations and **var**) within a function are scoped within that function.

In your example, the function `inner` exists only within `outer`'s scope; anything else than a Reference Error when trying to call `inner()` should be considered a "quirk".

---

**UPDATE:** [Found a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235360/what-is-the-scope-of-a-function-in-javascript-ecmascript) probably related to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "safe". 
In your example there is no way to invoke `inner()` from outside of `outer()`. If "safe" - means only function visibility, then your are right, it's safe.

Comment: By safe I meant is it possible they pollute global namespaces or are not treated as being local to the function they were declared in.

Comment: inner - is treated as being local to the outer